# Map of template function

Tags: c++

I have a class like this:

```cpp
class factory;

using factory_ptr = std::unique_ptr<IComponent> (factory::*)() const noexcept;

class factory {
    public:
        factory();
        ~factory() = default;
        std::unique_ptr<Chipset> &create(const std::string &type);
    private:
        template<class T>
        std::unique_ptr<T> Tcreate() const noexcept;
        std::map<std::string, factory_ptr> m_fac;
};

#include "factory.inl"
```

My template function `Tcreate` is just:

```cpp
template<class T>
std::unique_ptr<T> factory::Tcreate() const noexcept {
    return std::make_unique<T>();
}
```

And the other function are just:

```cpp
factory::factory() {
    m_fac.emplace("4001", &factory::Tcreate<chipset4001>);
    m_fac.emplace("4008", &factory::Tcreate<chipset4008>);
    m_fac.emplace("4011", &factory::Tcreate<chipset4011>);
    m_fac.emplace("4030", &factory::Tcreate<chipset4030>);
    m_fac.emplace("4069", &factory::Tcreate<chipset4069>);
    m_fac.emplace("4071", &factory::Tcreate<chipset4071>);
    m_fac.emplace("4081", &factory::Tcreate<chipset4081>);
    m_fac.emplace("4512", &factory::Tcreate<chipset4512>);
}

std::unique_ptr<Chipset> &factory::create(const std::string &type) {
    if (m_fac.find(type) == m_fac.end()) {
        throw nts::exception("can't find the chipset: " + type, "FactoryCreate");
    }
    return (this->*(m_fac.find(type)->second))();
}
```

Every chipset like `chipsetXXXX` are a class like:

```cpp
class chipsetXXXX : Chipset {}
```

What I want to do here with this code is to generate an `std::unique_ptr<>` of a certain chipset linked with a string (cf. `factory::m_fac`), but when I run it a lot of error message pop on my terminal (more than what my terminal can handle). but i can't figured out what go wrong with it.

Comment: You can redirect errors to a file in order to be able to see them, then go to the top of the file. I think in this case, without testing it, it's because you need to put the implementation of your template with the definition so the compiler knows how to actually expand it for you.

Comment: Ok, so with the redirection i found that the probleme come from the map with this error:
`no matching function for call to 'std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::unique_ptr<nts::IComponent> (nts::factory::*)() const noexcept>::pair(const char [5], std::unique_ptr<nts::chipset4001, std::default_delete<nts::chipset4001> > (nts::factory::*)() const noexcept)'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your `Tcreate` function does not have the required signature. You're trying to create a map of functions which return an `std::unique_ptr<IComponent>`, but `Tcreate()` returns `std::unique_ptr<T>`.

I'm assuming `Chipset` inherits from `IComponent`. And as you note each `T` inherits from `Chipset`. So the conversion from e.g. `std::unique_ptr<chipset4001>` to `std::unique_ptr<IComponent>` is certainly possible, but that doesn't mean that the signature matches. E.g. a pointer to a function `double do_thing ()` can't be assigned to a function pointer expecting an `int (*) ()`.

So the solution is to change the return type of `Tcreate` to `std::unique_ptr<IComponent>`:

```
template<class T>
std::unique_ptr<IComponent> factory::Tcreate() const noexcept {
    return std::make_unique<T>();
}
```

However, when you do that, you'll now get a compile error in `create()`, because that tries to return an `std::unique_ptr<Chipset>`. It's up to you to decide what to do there. Either return `std::unique_ptr<IComponent>`, or change `factory_ptr` to be a pointer to a function returning `std::unique_ptr<Chipset>` (and of course change `Tcreate()` accordingly).